# How do i solve this generic bug

Tags: java

i have the following code that won't compile because of generic problems. It comes from when i try to run the code. The problem is that i must fix the generic issue but i can't spot it whether i must change something in the class StAlgo or in the method.

```
public class StAlgo{

//signature selection sort
public <T extends Comparable<T>> int selectionSort(T[] array) {
}

 public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T[] getRandomPermutationOfIntegers(int size) {
      T[] data = (T[])new Comparable[size]; 
      for (Integer i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          data[i] = (T)i;
      }

      // shuffle the array
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          T temp;
          int swap = i + (int) ((size - i) * Math.random());
          temp = data[i];
          data[i] = data[swap];
          data[swap] = temp;
      }
      return data;
  }

 public <T extends Comparable<T>> void trySelectionSort(){
      int N = 100, M = 100;  

      for(int i= 0; i < N; i++){
          T[] arrayInts = (T[])new Comparable[i];
          for(int j= 0; j < M; i++){
              arrayInts = getRandomPermutationOfIntegers(i);
              //Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arrayInts));
              selectionSort(arrayInts);
          }
      }
  }
}







//Main class  has the folling code:

    StAlgosa s = new StAlgosa();
    s.trySelectionSort();
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Bound mismatch: The generic method trySelectionSort() of type StAlgosa is not applicable for the arguments (). The inferred type Comparable<Comparable<T>> is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<T>>
```

how do i fix it?

thanks

Comment: It would be useful to give out the stack trace.

Comment: No, not really. The "unresolved compilation problem" exception means this class just didn't compile, but he told Eclipse to run the program anyway. The line numbers wouldn't be meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a problem with Type Erasure - http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

When you do T extends Foo<T>, after compilation, Java just remembers T extends Foo.

Checkout [Generic Restriction Hell: Bound Mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751027/generic-restriction-hell-bound-mismatch) post for more information.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I can't compile it to print the stack trace

Comment: Oh. I thought you were getting an exception. Its the compilation process that's throwing up is it? My bad. Can you, then provide the line where the compiler is failing? That will help fix the exact issue

Comment: this line : s.trySelectionSort();

Comment: When I use this code, I get 2 errors - You have named the Class wrong i.e. StAlgosa and you are trying to assign data[i] = (T) i. These 2 are the only issues. I actually do not get an error otherwise at the place you have mentioned.

Comment: I see. The class name is not an issue with me. I made the mistake when copying to the text editor. My class names are intact. How do i fix data[i] = (T) i; ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4636/discussion-between-pavan-sudarshan-and-eddy-freeman)

Comment: You are trying to generate an array of random elements of type T. You would not be able to do that right? Since you do not know how to instantiate them.

Answer (score 1):

Partial fix is to have something like:

```
public class StAlgo<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

However, you will still have problem at

```
data[i] = (T) i;
```

because you are making Integers in that loop but your T type might not be implicitly assignable...